# Is there a way to make a div the same height of another div without both divs being in the same container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make all divs using the "details" class the same height. Since "details" div contains different content the height differs. I'd like to set a uniiform height for all divs using the "details" class. The reason why is that I plan on writing a script that highlights the background color of the div using classes "col-4 mouseover"

```html
<div class="col-4 mouseover">
  <div class="topheader">Header</div>
  <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.</div>
  <div class="details">Totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.Totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</div>
  <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.</div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 mouseover">
  <div class="topheader">Header</div>
  <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.</div>
  <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.</div>
  <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.</div>
</div>
<div class="col-4 mouseover">
  <div class="topheader">Header</div>
  <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.</div>
  <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.Lorem ipsum dolet
    sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.</div>
  <div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolet sid amet nonummy consecteur elit sed iam overit diddium sel.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MisterJojo Sure Example please. Will I be able to create the mouseover effect I'm looking for?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: can you provide image of the template you expecting ?